# how to delete input query value text

Tags: vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I would like to delete text query input for user entry in a vue-multiselect element before execute some functions.

if I do not  delete user text input, my data array is still filtered and I not access to the entire set of initial data

I tried to use jquery selector for set to null but user text is restored by vue I suppose.

thanks

please forgive my approximate English I am French.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Salut.Try to clear multiselect value programmatically. Work with data, but not with DOM.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    value: [{ text: 'TS', value: 1 }],
    options: [{ text: 'TS', value: 1 }, { text: 'JS', value: 2 }]
    // ...
    },
  methods: {
    // ...
    clearValue() {
        this.value = [];
        // or this.$set(this, 'value', []);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply : unfortunately data.value has user selected value not user input text :/

Comment: If issue is actual, it would be easier to solve that if you provide some example on jsfiddle.